# Filter Mongo document by date in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code parses html and gets string like "09/03/2017" and saves it to a mongodb collection like this:

```
const date = ResObj.$(this).next().html().trim();
const dArr = date.split('/');
const dObj = new Date(parseInt(dArr[2]), parseInt(dArr[1]) - 1, parseInt(dArr[0]));
myCol.update({_id:'abc', {$set:{date: dObj}}});
```

Later I need to return the documents between and include 2 dates say 09/03/2017.
The search string is being received from the client in the formate 2017-03-09.

```
myCol.find({date: {$gte: start, $lte: end}})
```

Moment.js is also installed. How can I do this so that the output is in the formate DD/MM/YYYY? thx

Comment: Are you just trying to find out how to format the date you are receiving from the database?

Comment: @Sean I am trying to find out how to formate the date so that it works in the `myCol.find` and also to be in the required representation formate DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is store your date as a date object, that way you can query against it in the DB.

To do that using moment, you need to parse the string in to a moment object. This is telling `moment` to create a date object using the date provided and telling it what format the date is in so it knows which is the days/months etc.

`const dateObj = moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate()`

You are then using the moment `toDate()` function to convert that in to a date object which you can store in the DB.

Save that to the DB

`myCol.update({_id:'abc', { $set:{ date: dateObj }}});`

Then, when you are back on the client you can format the output date using moment again

`const formattedDate = moment(dateFromDB).format("DD/MM/YYYY");`

Basically, you always want to store your dates in the DB as date objects, that way they can be used in querys and sorted etc. You only want to convert them back to strings using `format()` back on the client.

Comment: I had an old comment in the code indicating the reason I did not use moment being that it has an issue with hr being 14 not 00, really not sure if it is related, just thought to mention it if it means any thing to you.

Comment: I noticed your first line of code takes `dObj` as an argument. Isn't there a way that the variable holding "09/03/2017" gets used instead of doing extra 2 steps as stated in my code in order to get dObj?

Comment: Yes, you are right - I was too busy writing the solution to remember to get rid of your initial steps. I have updated my answer with more info

Comment: Back on the client, I need to do `myCol.find({date: {$gte: start, $lte: end}})` with `start` and `end` are being received from the client input in the formate YYYY-MM-DD. So now the mongodb find is not returning anything. How can this be fixed?

Comment: You need to convert the client input in to a date object as well. ```moment(clientDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").toDate()``` Then you can use it to query against